# Android threading, locks, concurrent example

Tags: java, android, multithreading, optimization, concurrency

Hi I was wonder how bad is it for performance to use Thread.sleep(x) in a while loop that is inside a thread that isn't the UI thread... is this not using cpu cycles ? For example

```
boolean[] flag = {false};    

//New thread to show some repeated animation
new Thread(new Runnnable{ run() {
    while(true){
        someImageView.animate()....setListener(.. onComplete(){ flag[0] = true; } ..).start();
    }

}).start()

//Wait for flag to be true to carry on in this thread
while(!flag[0]){
     Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `synchronized` block to be able to rely on `wait`/`notify`/`notifyAll` to synchronize your threads, you would not even need in your case to modify any state, any shared `Object` instance could be enough.

The code could be:

```
// Mutex to share between the threads waiting for the result.
Object mutex = new Object();
...
onComplete() { 
    synchronized (mutex) {
        // It is done so we notify the waiting threads
        mutex.notifyAll();
    }
}

synchronized (mutex) {
    // Wait until being notified
    mutex.wait();
}
```

Comment: I marked this as an answer because it rewrites the code without a sleep involved .. however I was looking for a bit more of a theoretical answer

Comment: offtopic: You are slowing down; I am almost catching up on you again ... keep going, just 1.5K left ;-) (did my part to help for today ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use `.join()` on a thread to wait for it to finish, so

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnnable{ run() {
    while(true){
        someImageView.animate()....setListener(..).start();
    }

});
thread.start();
thread.join();
```